# WorkManager: how is network constraint handled when AlarmManager is used?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

It seems to be that WorkManager uses AlarmManager under the hood for Android versions older than 21, because JobScheduler isn't available.  See e.g. [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/).

But when setting a network constraint with WorkManager along the following lines:

```
Constraints.Builder constraintsBuilder = new Constraints.Builder();
constraintsBuilder.setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED);
Constraints constraints = constraintsBuilder.build();

OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder workRequestBuilder = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class);
workRequestBuilder.setInitialDelay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
workRequestBuilder.setConstraints(constraints);
```

With a JobScheduler the behaviour seems to be that the scheduled job will just sit there until network is restored, and then it will fire immediately because the constraints are now met.

But Alarms are a bit different and don't naturally have an associated constraint.  So how is the network constraint actually handled for Android < 21 when it relies on AlarmManager?  If the alarm fires when there is no network, what happens then?  My limited experience so far is that this isn't handled well (or at all), and I'm wondering whether  need to handle the network constraint manually, by listening to `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`?

Comment: THe alarm could simply check for the internet and if it doesn't find it, reschedule.

Comment: @GabeSechan but reschedule for when?  Let's say I schedule a work (alarm) for 6 hours from now, and in six hours the alarm fires (with no network) what sensible decision can WorkManager make about when to reschedule the alarm?  Another six hours?  Arbitrary 5 mins, 1 min, or what?

Comment: You're going to have to dive into the OS code to figure that out, and I'd expect it to change over time as an implementation detail.  However I'd expect that JobScheduler does no better job-  both of them are layers written on top of AlarmManager, they aren't true bottom up replacements.

Comment: WorkManager already listens for `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`. There's nothing else you need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WorkManager already listens for `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` - just because it uses alarms doesn't mean that's the only signal it uses. There's nothing you need to do manually do; WorkManager does all of the constraint tracking for you.

Comment: That's what I'd expected, though it didn't seem to be working like that in practice.  Based on some observations with an emulator running 4.3, it didn't seem to be happening... i.e. I could see that a work was scheduled to fire (to refresh a widget) when the connectivity was off, but on re-establishing connectivity the work didn't seem to trigger.  I have switched back on my legacy code for watching `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` in my `AppWidgetProvider` (and *without* setting a network constraint on the work) and it's back behaving as I'd expect... widget refreshes immediately on restoring network.

Comment: My `AppWidgetProvider` was still registered to receive `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` when trying out WorkManager with network constraint... that wouldn't mess things up?  In `onReceive()` I do call `super.onReceive()` and WorkManager should still itself be able to make use of the connectivity change triggers to manage network-constrained work pre 21?  It just didn't seem to be happening for me.

Comment: I'll go back and check whether there is something else at play.  Your answer does give some reassurance to me that WorkManager *should* be doing what I expect it to be doing... and if it turns out to be the case that it provides a unified interface for scheduling jobs/work that is effective for all Android versions... that would be the holy grail for me... would be amazing.